# Cant properly read api json data

Tags: python

I was successful in extracting the data about matches I required in the first half of my code, but I can't seem the do the other part. I am reading JSON data and doing it in the same way really but I'm getting strings, not dictionaries with data. I'm sure it's a logic problem or something, please help me. I have the working part on my github : https://github.com/LEvinson2504/Football-Prediction-and-analysis

```
import urllib.request
import json

#Match odds
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request

def SportDemo():
    # Set url parameter

    url = "http://api.isportsapi.com/sport/free/football/odds/main?api_key=" + api_key

    # Call iSport Api to get data in json format
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    content = f.read()
    #data = json.loads((content.decode('utf-8')))
    data = content.decode('utf-8')

    '''store match ids

    matches = []

    #English teams match id
    for team in data['data']:
        if (team == 'English Premier League'):
            #store match ids
            matches.append(team['matchId'])

    '''

    #here is the problem, tried several ways to access data
    for i in data[data]:
        print(i['asia'])
    '''
    for match in data[data]['asia']:
        for coun in match:
            print(coun)
    '''
    '''
        if(match == 'asian'):
            print(type(match))
    '''
        #if (match['leagueName'] == 'ENG U23 D1'):
    #for odds in data['data']:
        #for i in matches:
        #print()


SportDemo()
```

Expected Output, and I want to read inside the dictionaries to get the data iside keys "europe", "asia"

Json data : https://www.isportsapi.com/docs?isportsDocIndex=1-4-24 like her, I'm sorry I couldn't format.

But i get nothing

Comment: Well you've commented out the `json.loads` line. Why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah I was trying to see if that was turning the list within a dict into string or something, but json.loads was the first thing i did, didn't work like it should, gave me strings when infact should return lists/dicts

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. `json.loads` will turn the string you receive into a dict.

Comment: @DanielRoseman exactly but the last, second last triple comma comments give me type string, I can't dig deeper to get the data. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when asking a question please take the time to tidy it up so that it represents what you actually ran and remove any commented-out code.

In your case, the problem can be reduced to:

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = f.read()
data = json.loads((content.decode('utf-8')))

#here is the problem, tried several ways to access data
for i in data[data]:
    print(i['asia'])
```

and we can actually see what the issue is. `data` is a dict; within that dict is a key `'data'`, which is *itself* a dict. Iterating through a dict gives you the *keys*. If you just want to access the 'asia' data, then do so, no need to loop at all:

```
print(data['data']['asia'])
```

If you did want to iterate through every item, then use `items()`:

```
for region, matches in data['data'].items():
    print(region)
    print(matches)
```

Answer (score -1):

The download data is too big. 6.2M
Change the jupyter notebook configuration file. (jupyter_notebook_config.py)
Edit ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

If you cannot find the file, 
$ jupyter notebook --generate-config

Open the file and edit.

c.NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit = 10000000

and restart $ jupyter notebook.

```
url = "http://api.isportsapi.com/sport/free/football/odds/main?api_key=" + api_key


# Call iSport Api to get data in json format
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
content = f.read()

#print(content.decode('utf-8'))
data = json.loads((content.decode('utf-8')))
print( data['data']['asian'])
# there is no 'asia' field in that content.
```

Output is

```
[{'matchId': '4196461', 'companyId': '1', 'initialHandicap': '-0.25', 'initialHome': '0.78', 'initialAway': '1.02', 'instantHandicap': '-0.25', 'instantHome': '0.78', 'instantAway': '1.02', 'modifyTime': 1567434821, 'close': False, 'inPlay': False}, {'matchId': '4196461', 'companyId': '3', 'initialHandicap': '-0.25', 'initialHome': '0.91', 'initialAway': '0.91', 'instantHandicap': '-0.25', 'instantHome': '0.81', 'instantAway': '1.09', 'modifyTime': 1567709243, 'close': False, 'inPlay': True}, {'matchId': '4196461', 'companyId': '8', 'initialHandicap': '-0.25', 'initialHome': '0.85', 'initialAway': '1.00', 'instantHandicap': '-0.25', 'instantHome': '0.80', 
...
```